# Postgis: Punching Out/Cutting Out Courtyards With Two Polygon Tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis, polygon

i have two tables containing each a geom column. The first one called "table_outside" contains the building structure and the second one "table_inside" contains the courtyards of each building if there is one. Only using "table_outside" does not reflect the real structure.

I can't figure out how to punch out/cut out the couryards from the "table_outside", not to mention how to do it if there is another building inside the courtyard. At the end I would like to have a new table called "table_modification".

The Image below shows my problem (it's from wiki but with no additional information)

[image]

This is the code I was using. Note: vt_views is the materialized view where all my tables are. The execution took ~30mins for ~5.000.000 Buildings but the new table is not showing up in pgadmin4.

```
-- Get all the building_core with building_courtyards, with the building_courtyards cut out
CREATE TABLE vt_views.dtk50_gebaeude_mod AS WITH building_core AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vt_views.building_core
),
building_courtyard AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vt_views.building_courtyard
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT building_core.id AS building_core_id,
    ST_Difference(
        building_core.geom,
        (
            SELECT
                ST_Union(building_courtyard.geom) -- Correlated subquery to fetch only the building_courtyards intersected by the current building_core
            FROM
                building_courtyard
            WHERE
                ST_Intersects(
                    building_courtyard.geom,
                    building_core.geom
                )
        )
    ) AS geom
FROM
    building_core,
    building_courtyard
WHERE
    ST_Intersects(
        building_courtyard.geom,
        building_core.geom
    );
 
 
-- otherwise give blank geom columns for the no-hits
-- Now add all the building_core that have no building_courtyards
WITH building_core AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vt_views.building_core
),
building_courtyard AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vt_views.building_courtyard
),
all_building_courtyards AS (
    SELECT
        ST_Union(building_courtyard.geom) AS geom
    FROM
        building_courtyard
)
INSERT INTO
    vt_views.building_courtyard_cuts_into_building_core
SELECT
    building_core.id AS building_core_id,
    building_core.geom as geom
FROM
    building_core,
    all_building_courtyards
WHERE
    NOT ST_Intersects(
        all_building_courtyards.geom,
        building_core.geom
    )
```

Comment: Sounds like you need st_difference http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html

Comment: I know that but did not manage to get the codes working I already found on stackoverflow.

Comment: For example this one:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187406/how-to-use-st-difference-and-st-intersection-in-case-of-multipolygons-postgis

Comment: What have you tried? Post a couple of geometries and the queries you have tried...

Comment: I just edited the original question above.